# Create general function to close modal angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, uikit

I'm using Uikit/angularjs and i would create a general function to close the modals. Actually this is method:

```
$scope.closeDialog = function() {
            var modal = UIkit.modal("#myModalId");
            if ( modal.isActive() ) {
                modal.hide();
            }
        };
```

and inside the modal i've got

```
<button type="button" class="uk-button uk-button-primary" data-ng-click="closeDialog()">Close</button>
```

It works, but in this way i need create always a new function for every single Modal.. Is there a way to generalize this function maybe pass to the function the id of the dialog? I created a jsfiddle and strangly seems not working even if i get the exaclty id:
http://jsfiddle.net/8y48q/62/

Comment: Why not have a service managing your modals? You could wrap the functionality of the library you are using in there, in your own open and close methods and call these instead.

Answer (score 1):

```
$scope.closeDialog = function(id) {
            $modalStack.dismissAll();
        };
```

This will dismiss all modals

http://jsfiddle.net/8y48q/64/

Answer (score 0):

Just pass the id to the closeDialog. See http://jsfiddle.net/8y48q/63/

```
$scope.closeDialog = function(id) {
    var modal = UIkit.modal(id);
    if ( modal.isActive() ) {
         modal.hide();
    }
};
```